# BMW 316i (2013) - Start remotely using smart phone

Tags: bmw, remote-start

I would like to start my car remotely using some smartphone app.

The reason is I live in Dubai and the temperatures here are crazy, when I leave office or any where else, the interior of the car is so hot that you cant sit inside. Everytime I leave office I start my car, pump up the AC and wait at the very least for 5 minutes somewhere in the shade before I can enter the car and at that point the car is still not comfortable. I have to wait at least 10 mins before the car becomes comfortable.

To counter all this it would be a blessing if I can start my car remotely, so that the car starts and so does the AC and then 10-15 mins later I leave office and reach the car. Is there some after market device/system using which maybe I could start the car remotely with a smartphone maybe.

Comment: I see a risk with unattended running in a hot environment.  If anything goes wrong, say with the cooling system, you will not be there to notice.  Is having a cool car worth the increased risk of cooking the car should something decide to not run right one day?

Answer (score 2):

In fact there is, some of the top end alarm systems offer a function to start the car remotely. Python has a model that offers this function along with sat nav car location and radar alarm trigger.

For the safety of your car, talk to a professional alarm specialist as this is quite sensitive setup and needs to integrate with the BMW wiring seamlessly and securely.